# Pandas get_dummies to create one hot with separator = ' ' and with character level separation

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["c", "b", "a p", NaN, "ap"])
df[0].str.get_dummies(' ')
```

The above code prints something like this.

```
       a   p    b    c ap 
0      0   0    0    1  0
1      0   0    1    0  0 
2      1   1    0    0  0
3      0   0    0    0  0
4      0   0    0    0  1
```

The required output is the following:

```
       a   p    b    c  
0      0   0    0    1 
1      0   0    1    0  
2      1   1    0    0 
3      0   0    0    0 
4      1   1    0    0
```

I am sure it's bit tricky. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer linked at the top of the question was helpful. Namely:
# Create a dataframe of dummy vars
col0_dummy_df = df['0'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
# Concatenate dummy variable dataframe onto main dataframe.
pd.concat([df, col0_dummy_df], axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `str.get_dummies`

```
df[0].str.get_dummies(sep=' ')
Out[745]: 
   air  bus  car  plane
0    0    0    1      0
1    0    1    0      0
2    1    0    0      1
```

Or

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df[0].str.split().tolist()).stack()).sum(level=0)
Out[754]: 
   air  bus  car  plane
0    0    0    1      0
1    0    1    0      0
2    1    0    0      1
```

Comment: This time I am 12 seconds ahead, actually just 3 :)

Comment: @Vaishali haha, show on my side I am 4 sec :-)

Comment: I really appreciate your previous answers. @Wen If you can answer this latest edit, it is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.get_dummies

```
df[0].str.get_dummies(' ')


    air bus car plane
0   0   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   1
```

Comment: I really appreciate your previous answers. @Vaishali If you can answer this latest edit, it is really helpful