# One-hot encoding for list variable with customized delimiter and new column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

My data:

```
Rank    Platforms        Technology

high    Windows||Linux   Unity
high    Linux             
low     Windows          Unreal 
low     Linux||MacOs     GameMakerStudio||Unity||Unreal
low                      GameMakerStudio
low
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
Rank    platform_Windows  platform_linux  platform_MacOs technology_unity  technology_unreal technology_GameMakerStudio

high    1                 0                0             1                  0                   1
high    0                 1                0             0                  0                   0
low     1                 0                0             0                  1                   0 
low     0                 1                1             1                  1                   1 
low     0                 0                0             0                  0                   1
low     0                 0                0             0                  0                   0
```

So it's sort of one-hot encoding. I have followed many answers:

1. [How to one-hot-encode from a pandas column containing a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312377/how-to-one-hot-encode-from-a-pandas-column-containing-a-list/45312840)
2. [Pandas get_dummies to create one hot with separator = ' ' and with character level separation [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420338/pandas-get-dummies-to-create-one-hot-with-separator-and-with-character-lev)
3. [ow to one-hot-encode from a pandas column containing a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312377/how-to-one-hot-encode-from-a-pandas-column-containing-a-list)

The issues are:

- none of them shows how to separate my list by `||` delimiter
- none of them shows how to prefix the new column name. For example `platform_` and `technology_`. I need this to know which original column the new column comes from.

My current code is:

```
df.drop('Platforms', 1).join(
    pd.get_dummies(
        pd.DataFrame(df.Platforms.str.split("||").tolist()).stack(),
        prefix=['platform']
    ).assum(level=0)
)

df.drop('Technology', 1).join(
    pd.get_dummies(
        pd.DataFrame(df.Technology.str.split("||").tolist()).stack(),
        prefix=['technology']
    ).assum(level=0)
)
```

But the error I get is:

> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

I have read the document [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [pandas.Series.str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html). The latter seems to accept a customized delimiter while the former allows customized new column prefixes...

Comment: `df.Platforms.str.get_dummies()` seems to work as exptected.

Comment: @Quang Hoang it does not allow prefix to column name `platform_` and `technology_`

Comment: Don't be lazy, just chain it: `df.Platforms.str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Platform_')` :D

Comment: Oh, at a second look, it yields a `None` column. Which could be drop afterwards.

Comment: @QuangHoang could you post a full working code as answer? Thank you

Comment: Did you ask this already?

Comment: @DanielMesejo just similar example, here I mention 2 issues: column prefix and customize delimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
s = [df[col].str.get_dummies().add_prefix(f'{col.lower()}_') 
        for col in ['Platforms', 'Technology']]

pd.concat([df[['Rank']]] + s, axis=1)
```